# Intermittent unit test failure due to CompletableFuture.thenAccept not running

Tags: java, completable-future

I have a method that collects data from multiple factories using CompletableFuture.supplyAsync like below

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.StrictStubs.class)
public class TestThenApply {

    @Mock private Factory1 factory1;
    @Mock private Factory2 factory2;
    @Mock private Factory3 factory3;

    @Test
    public void case1() throws Exception {
        when(factory1.create()).thenReturn("factory1");
        when(factory2.create()).thenReturn("factory2");
        when(factory3.create()).thenReturn("factory3");

        Map<String, Object> expected = new HashMap<>();
        expected.put("factory1", "factory1");
        expected.put("factory2", "factory2");
        expected.put("factory3", "factory3");

        assertEquals(expected, getModel());
    }

    @Test
    public void case2() throws Exception {
        when(factory1.create()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Test!!"));
        when(factory2.create()).thenReturn("factory2");
        when(factory3.create()).thenReturn("factory3");

        Map<String, Object> expected = new HashMap<>();
        expected.put("factory1", null);
        expected.put("factory2", "factory2");
        expected.put("factory3", "factory3");

        assertEquals(expected, getModel());
    }

    @Test
    public void case3() throws Exception {
        when(factory1.create()).thenReturn("factory1");
        when(factory2.create()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Test!!"));
        when(factory3.create()).thenReturn("factory3");

        Map<String, Object> expected = new HashMap<>();
        expected.put("factory1", "factory1");
        expected.put("factory2", null);
        expected.put("factory3", "factory3");

        assertEquals(expected, getModel());
    }

    @Test
    public void case4() throws Exception {
        when(factory1.create()).thenReturn("factory1");
        when(factory2.create()).thenReturn("factory2");
        when(factory3.create()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Test!!"));

        Map<String, Object> expected = new HashMap<>();
        expected.put("factory1", "factory1");
        expected.put("factory2", "factory2");
        expected.put("factory3", null);

        assertEquals(expected, getModel());
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getModel() {

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        CompletableFuture<Void> factory1Future = supplyAsyncWithCallable("factory1", () -> factory1.create())
                .thenAccept(result -> map.put("factory1", result));
        CompletableFuture<Void> factory2Future = supplyAsyncWithCallable("factory2", () -> factory2.create())
                .thenAccept(result -> map.put("factory2", result));
        CompletableFuture<Void> factory3Future = supplyAsyncWithCallable("factory3", () -> factory3.create())
                .thenAccept(result -> map.put("factory3", result));


        CompletableFuture.allOf(factory1Future, factory2Future, factory3Future).join();

        return map;
    }

    private <T> CompletableFuture<T> supplyAsyncWithCallable(String widgetName, Callable<T> widgetModelBuilder) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                return widgetModelBuilder.call();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have 4 unit tests which tests below scenarios

1. When all 3 factories succeeds // Happy case
2. When `factory1` fails but other 2 factories succeed
3. When `factory2` fails but other 2 factories succeed
4. When `factory3` fails but other 2 factories succeed

90% of the time all these test cases pass however one test case fails (assertion error) randomly sometimes.

I suspect this might be because `thenAccept` does not run before the main thread ends. I was able to get it working all the time by moving all the `thenAccept` logic after the `join()`. However I don't want to do that unless I have to. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the assertion error saying? That what you're doing in `thenAccept` did not occur? That's something you should know for sure.

Comment: Yes, one of the entry is missing in the returned map. Sorry I should have mentioned this in the post.

Comment: Can't see how that can happen given that you're blocking with `join()`. Are you catching potential exception or something like that? Perhaps posting code closer to your real one will help.

Comment: Yes I am kinda, so my `factory.create()` method throws a checked exception hence I wrapped it with a try/catch in a helper method before passing it to `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync`. May be that is causing this ? I will update the question with code closer to the real one shortly.

Comment: Updated the code in the question which is similar to my code. If you run all these tests one of the test fails randomly

Comment: It's always quite a strong sign when an exception is caught and ignored. You should probably start by logging the exception (printing the stack trace or something). From what the code looks like, if `widgetModelBuilder.call()` throws an exception, your assertions will fail because `null` will be put into the map. And I assume that you're checking with `map.get("factory3") != null` rather than `map.containsKey("factory3")` (which would probably succeed)

Comment: I am actually checking if map has an entry with `factory1` as the key and `null` as the value is when `factory1` throws an exception. I just ran the above test file 5-6 times one test failed randomly.

Comment: If I move the `thenAccept` call after `join()` all test cases pass.

Comment: I don't think this is likely to be the problem though, but have you looked into the fact that you're using a hash map in concurrent calls? A hash map isn't thread-safe and maybe, just maybe, something is amiss.

Comment: Wow!! that was it. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ernest_k

Using HashMap was the issue here. Replaced it with thread safe map and now the test cases pass consistently.